# Geocode Autocomplete mobile

Tags: android, ios, autocomplete, geocoding

I am trying to set up autocomplete with geocoding. If the user is typing in a name of a city, I want him get a few cities as a result. Vice versa with postal codes.

The new policy from google seems way too expensive (70.000 autocomplete requests = 200$ ?? )
I tried to solve it with the Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Geocoding implementation, but this does not seem to work at all... at least not under iOs. The result of GetPositionsForAddressAsync or GetAddressesForPositionAsync does return a List, but no matter what input I provides, it only contains just one value.

So in your opinion: What ist the best and cheapest way to accomplish a geocoding autocomplete solution? I have no problem spending money for it... I am just looking for the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at OpenStreetMap based geocoders with autocompletion support, e.g. [Photon](http://photon.komoot.de/). It's open-source as well.

Comment: Photon in the link above doesn't exist any more. Any other suggestion?